# Tracking downloads using Google Analytics (ga.js)

Tags: google-analytics

I am having problems getting my event tracking working for some downloads on our site. Here is the code that I have inserted on the page. The code does execute when I click the link, but I am not seeing the event show up in the live viewer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href').match(/\/showdocument\?id\=\d+$/ig)) {
            );
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','DocumentManager','click',$(this).attr('href')])
        }
        if ($(this).attr('href').match(/.*\.mankatomn\.gov.*(\.pdf|\.mp3)$/ig)){
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','DocumentManager','click',$(this).attr('href')])
        }
     });
});
```

I am missing something obvious here? I haven't worked much with GA except for pasting the code they give me to the page in the past.

Comment: Have you tried using GA Debugger to see if the hit goes through?

Comment: Didn't know that existed. I'll take a look.

Comment: I am getting "Tracking beacon sent!" so it must be working. I guess I'll have to wait and see on Monday if it's getting posted.

Comment: yeah, real-time isn't always reliable, but just check with GA Debugger, and also check in your Network console to see if you can see the "utm" hit go through.

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out the issue was that I was filtering out our IP address so I wasn't seeing the results because of it. Once I removed it, it started working. :-/